# File IO: len() function not working properly in python

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to do File IO, and I wrote a program to:

1. Read the following lines
2. Print what line number each line is on
3. Print the total characters in a line
4. Print the line.

The text I'm trying to read is stored in a file called **input.txt**. Here is the exact text...

```
I am a file.
This is a line.
This is the last line.
```

and here is my function to read that file and print out my desired results.

```
in1 = open("input.txt", 'r')
x=0
for line in in1:
    print ('Line %d ' % (x)),
    print ("(%d chars): " % (len(line))),
    print (line),

    x += 1
```

My terminal output **should** be

```
Line 0 (12 chars): I am a file.
Line 1 (15 chars): This is a line.
Line 2 (22 chars): This is the last line.
```

But my actual terminal output is

```
Line 0 (13 chars): I am a file.
Line 1 (16 chars): This is a line.
Line 2 (22 chars): This is the last line.
```

When my function is counting the length of the line, I believe it is counting the *Enter Key* I press in order to move to the next line as an extra character. How do I fix this?

Comment: What is `x += 1x=0` supposed to be? As it is it is definitely a syntax error.

Comment: You need to strip the newline character(s) at the end with `line.rstrip()`. Also, it's generally preferred to use a `with open("input.txt", "r") as in1:` block when using files.

Comment: the x += 1x=0 was a mistake in my original post. I've updated it to be x += 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because each line has a new-line character at the end that you don't see.  Use `len(line.rstrip())` instead.